# Loading Bay Lights Detection with OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am not a programmer but I am trying to make a simple app on android. It is supposed to recognize which light is currently on ( RED OR GREEN ). I did lots of research and followed few tutorials.[This was one of my guides how to do it](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/300581967_Traffic_Light_Recognition_System_for_People_with_Color_Blindness). My case is much more simple as light is always stationary and user have aim camera on lights. I did blue box with adjusted size on a screen and only in that area program is looking for red and green lights. But the accuracy of detecting an object is it that good as I wish too. What can I do to improve it? Without using deep Learning which is black magic at this moment for me :) I thought my next step would be  creating a mask with red and green circles and compare which circle got brighter pixels so this way i could decide which light is on.[Something smilar to that tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/31/detecting-multiple-bright-spots-in-an-image-with-python-and-opencv/)

There is a code which i got so far. [This is how program looks like](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oflN7ltue-UC5v_sbW8_wtcT8cFgCrjf/view?usp=sharing)  You can see that app is a bit laggy on this movie but after i started using SubMat insted of whole Mat it isnt laggy anymore.

If anyone can help me somehow with it I would be very grateful
What if i would like to use deep learning ? How to start?

```js
package com.gavreel.jrs.baylightalarm;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2{


    SeekBar seekBar;
    double areaOfIntrestSize ;

    Mat mRgba;
    Mat grayScaleRED;
    Mat imgHSV;
    Mat imgREDThreshold;
    Mat imgREDThreshold2;
    Mat greenThreshold ;
    Mat red_Threshold;
    Mat red_rgb_image;
    Mat green_rgb;
    Mat green_greyScale;

    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();

                }
                break;
                default: {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        seekBar.setMax(20);
        seekBar.setProgress(10);
        areaOfIntrestSize = 0.04 * seekBar.getProgress();
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                        if(seekBar.getProgress()==0) seekBar.setProgress(1);
                        areaOfIntrestSize = 0.04 * seekBar.getProgress();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }
                });



        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.CV_cameraView);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCameraIndex(0);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        super.onResume();
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, mLoaderCallback);
        } else {
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        grayScaleRED = new Mat();
        mRgba = new Mat();
        imgHSV = new Mat();
        imgREDThreshold =  new Mat();
        imgREDThreshold2 =  new Mat();
        greenThreshold = new Mat();
        red_Threshold= new Mat();
        red_rgb_image = new Mat();
        green_rgb = new Mat();
        green_greyScale = new Mat();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {

    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

        Size orig = mRgba.size();
        double offx = 0.5 * (1.0-areaOfIntrestSize) * orig.width;
        double offy = 0.5 * (1.0-areaOfIntrestSize) * orig.height;
       // Mat cropped =  Mat.zeros(mRgba.size(),mRgba.type());
        //Imgproc.rectangle(cropped,new Point(offx,offy), new Point(orig.width-offx,orig.height-offy), new Scalar(255,255,255),-1);
        Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba,new Point(offx,offy), new Point(orig.width-offx,orig.height-offy), new Scalar(48,151,255),8);
        Mat cropped = mRgba.submat((int)offy,(int)(orig.height-offy),(int) offx,(int)(orig.width-offx));
/*
        float zoom = 0.2f;
        Size orig = mRgba.size();
        double offx = 0.5 * (1.0-zoom) * orig.width;
        double offy = 0.5 * (1.0-zoom) * orig.height;


        Mat cropped2 = mRgba.submat((int)offy,(int)(orig.height-offy),(int) offx,(int)(orig.width-offx));
        // resize to original:
       Imgproc.resize(cropped, cropped, orig);
      Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba,new Point(offx,offy), new Point(orig.width-offx,orig.height-offy), new Scalar(255),8);
*/


        Imgproc.cvtColor(cropped,imgHSV,Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(imgHSV,imgHSV,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
        Imgproc.medianBlur(imgHSV,imgHSV,3);




        Core.inRange(imgHSV, new Scalar(45,60,60),new Scalar(75,255,255),greenThreshold); // green
        Core.inRange(imgHSV, new Scalar(0,100,100),new Scalar(3,255,255), imgREDThreshold2); // red
        Core.inRange(imgHSV, new Scalar(170,100,100), new Scalar(179,255,255), imgREDThreshold); // red

        imgHSV.release();

        Core.addWeighted(imgREDThreshold2,1.0, imgREDThreshold,1.0,0.0,red_Threshold); // redThreshold + redThreshold2
        imgREDThreshold.release();
        imgREDThreshold2.release();


       cropped.copyTo(green_rgb,greenThreshold);
       cropped.copyTo(red_rgb_image,red_Threshold);


        cropped.release();

        Imgproc.cvtColor(red_rgb_image,grayScaleRED,Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(green_rgb,green_greyScale,Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);


        circleDetection(grayScaleRED,offx,offy,new Scalar(255));
        circleDetection(green_greyScale,offx,offy,new Scalar( 50,180,50));




       // Imgproc.cvtColor(result,grayScaleLD,Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
       // Imgproc.threshold(grayScaleLD,brighestRed,150,255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
        //Core.MinMaxLocResult minMaxLocResultBlur = Core.minMaxLoc(grayScaleLD);
      // mRgba.copyTo(light,brighestRed);

      green_greyScale.release();
      grayScaleRED.release();
      greenThreshold.release();
      red_Threshold.release();
      red_rgb_image.release();
      green_rgb.release();









        return mRgba;
    }


void circleDetection ( Mat mGrey,double xoffset , double yoffset, Scalar scalarColor ){

    Mat circles = new Mat();
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mGrey,mGrey,new Size(5,5),0,0);
    Mat kelner = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.CV_SHAPE_ELLIPSE,new Size(2,2));
    Imgproc.erode(mGrey,mGrey,kelner);
    Imgproc.dilate(mGrey,mGrey,kelner);
    Imgproc.threshold(mGrey,mGrey,0,255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
    Imgproc.HoughCircles(mGrey,circles,Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 200, 120, 10, 2, 30);

    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
    int r = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < circles.cols(); i++ ) {
        double[] data = circles.get(0, i);
        for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            x = data[0];
            y = data[1];
            r = (int) data[2];
        }


        Imgproc.circle(mRgba,new Point(x+xoffset,y+yoffset),r,scalarColor,6);

    }


    circles.release();
    kelner.release();
    mGrey.release();
}

}
```